# Why do I get "unknown revision" when I try to make a patch?

Tags: 10

I am following the instructions for making a patch at:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/git/using-git-to-contribute-to-drupal/working-with-patches/making-a-patch

The module and release I am attempting to patch is https://www.drupal.org/project/infogram/releases/2.0.0

Step 5 of the instructions for making a patch say to do...

```
git diff origin/BASE_VERSION
```

I have tried the following:

```
git diff origin/2.0.0
git diff origin/2.0
git diff origin/2.0.x-dev
```

In all cases, I see messages like...

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin/2.0.0': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
```

What is the correct BASE_VERSION if I am trying to patch infogram 2.0.0?

(Note: 2.0.0 is identical to 2.0.x-dev at the moment, so I'm not sure it matters if I target 2.0.0 or 2.0.x-dev.)

- The git version is 2.39.1.windows.1
- The Drupal version is 10.1.6

Comment: Just use `2.0.0`, drop the origin.

Comment: Yes. ^ Tags don't have branches. This isn't a Drupal question.